# Level Array in Java

Tags: javascript, java, arrays

I have recently migrated from JS and the Processing library to LibGDX with Java. In my time with JS, I have used code like this, for level design:

```
var level = [
    " aaaaaaaaa",
    " aaaaaaaaa",
    " aaaaaaaaa",
    " aaaaaaaaa",
    " aaaaaaaaa",
    "aaaaaaaaaa",
    "aaaaaaaaaa",
    "saaaggaaaa",
    "ggggccgggg",
    "cccccccccc",
    "aaaaaaaaaa",
    "aaaaaaaaaa",
    "cccccccccc"
];
```

With this, I made a for loop and switch like so:

```
for(var c = 0; c < level.length; c ++){ 
    for(var r = 0; r < level[c].length; r ++){
        switch(level[c][r]) {
            case 'a':
                rect(r*40, c*40, 40, 40);
                break;
            case 'g':
                ...
        }
    }
}
```

This checks through each character in each string in the array. Due to Java's more abstract system of variables and lack of interchangeable array and string properties, I have found it very difficult to do this same thing in Java. Does anyone know of a way that I can? Thanks in advance!

Comment: [Arrays](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/arrays.html) and [the switch statement](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/switch.html)

Comment: I had loaded my "Java is not Javascript" gun but this time it's actually a question about both languages :D

Comment: By the way Java, as a language, is much better than Javascript and it does not lack anything JS could ever have. JS is a terrible language which happens to be the most used so people came up with lots of librairies which make it less terrible... but it is still a deeply flawed language.Be happy for having migrated

Comment: @Dici last time I tried Java in a web browser it had some serious problems :)

Comment: @Pointy `{} + {}` returns `NaN` in Javascript, and it's just one of the absurdities of the type system. Should I add something ?

Comment: @Dici: Java lacks an easy way to declare functions and pass them around as first-class values. Other than that, yes, almost every aspect Java is much more sanely designed than JavaScript.

Comment: @NayukiMinase yep, it does not have that and lambda do not really replace it. That's why I prefer Scala (as well as many other reasons !). Anyway, sorry for having started a language debate

Comment: @Dici, Pointy, Nayuki-Minase: This thread is now officially a JavaScript-bashing thread. All further comments on this post that do not involve criticism of JavaScript will be considered off-topic as will be promptly removed as such. /s

Comment: @Dici Haha, I would be ready too if I were you. And although I do agree mostly with you, when it comes to beginners, Javascript is much better, and NayukiMinase proves why. But yes, I do prefer Java. Yet I'm not moving completely away from JS, mainly I'm just moving on to other things than web dev. :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's very similar in Java.

```
String[] level = {
            " aaaaaaaaa",
            " aaaaaaaaa",
            " aaaaaaaaa",
            " aaaaaaaaa",
            " aaaaaaaaa",
            "aaaaaaaaaa",
            "aaaaaaaaaa",
            "saaaggaaaa",
            "ggggccgggg",
            "cccccccccc",
            "aaaaaaaaaa",
            "aaaaaaaaaa",
            "cccccccccc"
};
for(int c = 0; c < level.length; c ++){
    for(int r = 0; r < level[c].length(); r ++){
        switch(level[c].charAt(r)) {
            case 'a':
                // do something    
                break;
            case 'g':
                // etc   
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Works perfectly! Thanks so much! :D

Comment: Can you help me again? I am wondering how to append a new instance of a certain class to an array that is meant to hold those instances in place of `// do something`, and then call the appropriate methods by looping through the array. Do you get what I'm trying to do? Thanks in advance!